# How to join two pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables, table **A** and table **B**, both have same column names. I want to create a dataframe which will have table **B** have it's data added to the rows below data from table **A**.

My code however creates duplicate columns instead of just stacking table **B** below table **A**.

```
df = pd.merge(df_A, df_B, on=['mobile_number'])
```

How do I go about solving this.

Comment: Can you create a small test sample with two dataframes show your errant output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pd.concat(). it takes a iterable (i.e list) of dataframes and stacks them on top of each other like 'UNION ALL' in SQL